# Create different launcher for different Product Flavor

Tags: android, gradle, android-productflavors

I'm writing an application with multiple flavor on Android Studio using Gradle build system. Main app/AndroidManifest file have it's own Defined Launcher Activity and this I wanted to override by Flavor/AndroidManifest file where I have define other launcher activity which part of only Flavor/source code.

**Edit: Here's File Hierarchy:**

AppName->app->src->

- src->Flavor1->AndroidManifest
- src->Flavor2->AndroidManifest
- src->main->AndroidManifest

But when I do that it give exception with Main_app/package/launcher not found. Any suggestion here !

Comment: Could you show us your file hierarchy?

Comment: If your app is crashing, and you want help, you need to provide us with a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the problem. In this case, it would include full stack traces and manifest contents at minimum.

Comment: Thanks..I'm debugging it with other option..will update soon. If have any suggestion to follow/check process..please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Check your configuration settings:

[image: Edit Configurations]

[image: Change starting activity]

I had the same problem until I realized that it was using a flavor-specific activity for all flavors' starting activity configurations